# I keep getting TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to plot the paths, from the centeroid node in the middle of the neighbor, to the closest pharmacy and green are(parks).

```py
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the place (neighborhood) you want to analyze
place_name = "Ortabayır Mahallesi, Kâğıthane, Istanbul, Marmara Region, 34413, Turkey"

# Define the key-value pairs for the tags
tags = {'leisure': 'park', 'amenity': 'pharmacy'}

# Retrieve the street network graph for the specified place
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type="all")

# Get the centroid of the place
place_polygon = ox.geocode_to_gdf(place_name)
centroid = place_polygon.to_crs(graph.graph['crs']).geometry.centroid.values[0]

# Find the nearest nodes to the centroid for each amenity
nearest_nodes = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(graph, centroid.x, centroid.y, return_dist=True)

# Get the node IDs and distances
node_ids = nearest_nodes[0]
distances = nearest_nodes[1]

# Get the node ID of the closest pharmacy and park
pharmacy_node_id = node_ids[tags['amenity']]
park_node_id = node_ids[tags['leisure']]

# Get the shortest path from the centroid to the closest pharmacy and park
path_to_pharmacy = nx.shortest_path(graph, centroid, pharmacy_node_id)
path_to_park = nx.shortest_path(graph, centroid, park_node_id)

# Plot the street network graph
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(graph, figsize=(10, 10), node_size=0, show=False, close=False)

# Plot the paths to the closest pharmacy and park
ox.plot_graph_route(graph, path_to_pharmacy, route_color='blue', route_linewidth=3, ax=ax, show=False)
ox.plot_graph_route(graph, path_to_park, route_color='green', route_linewidth=3, ax=ax, show=False)

# Plot the centroid point
ax.scatter(centroid.x, centroid.y, color='red', s=50, label='Centroid')

# Plot the closest pharmacy and park nodes
ax.scatter(graph.nodes[pharmacy_node_id]['x'], graph.nodes[pharmacy_node_id]['y'], color='blue', s=50, label='Closest Pharmacy')
ax.scatter(graph.nodes[park_node_id]['x'], graph.nodes[park_node_id]['y'], color='green', s=50, label='Closest Park')

# Set the legend and title
ax.legend()
ax.set_title('Shortest Paths to Closest Pharmacy and Park')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Which results in the following error:

```
<ipython-input-64-15e170e5a960>:16: UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'centroid' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.

centroid = place_polygon.to_crs(graph.graph['crs']).geometry.centroid.values[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-15e170e5a960> in <cell line: 26>()
     24 
     25 # Get the node ID of the closest pharmacy and park
---> 26 pharmacy_node_id = node_ids[tags['amenity']]
     27 park_node_id = node_ids[tags['leisure']]
     28 

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: The TypeError clearly states that node_ids is an int